# Send POST request to Oracle APEX or PLSQL procedure

Tags: plsql, http-post, oracle-apex

I'm trying to send a post request with parameters to Oracle APEX or PL/SQL procedure in the database. I'm currently exploring these avenues but to no avail. The PL/SQL method seems to involve using a DAD(Database Access Descriptor) to make a PL/SQL procedure web-enabled - however this sounds too complicated and not really ideal for the current environment where I am working in - need to edit the HTTP server and all that.

I'm not sure if Oracle APEX can accept a POST request and process that. Does anyone know of any solution of how either APEX could read a POST request or a PL/SQL procedure could be called using url and POST request parameters passed to it.

Comment: what platform are you currently working on? Do you need it to work as a Web Service? Could you specify a little more on the post parameters and the nature of the PL/SQL procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create a RESTful web service in APEX, assuming your client is able to make a HTTP request, which is kind of a given.

Have a look at this article. It should give you enough information to be able to create a REST API with the appropriate endpoint and POST handler.

http://www.modernapex.co.uk/building-a-todo-app-with-rest/